# Get the return value of date diff?

Tags: java, sql-server, return, datediff

So i have this query using [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) function on MS SQL Server?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,(select StartDate from CarOrder where OrderID= 59),(select EndDate from CarOrder where OrderID= 59))
```

This work fine and the result is 10 but i dont know how to get the return value and use it in this function for java

```
public int getDateDiff(int OrderID){
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
    int datediff;
    String getdiffSQL = "SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,(select StartDate from CarOrder where OrderID = ? ) ,(select EndDate from CarOrder where OrderID= ?) )";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(getdiffSQL);
        pstm.setInt(1, OrderID);
        pstm.setInt(2, OrderID);            
        int nRows = pstm.executeUpdate();
        return nRows;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DBConnection.closeConnection(conn);
    }

}
```

i want it to return the date diff number so that it is a variable i can use in java, how can i do this ?
Thank You.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is wrong with the code you have above?

Comment: there isnt any thing wrong i just need to get the return value from datediff and get it to be a variable i can use in java.

Comment: Not relevant to your question but the query would be better as `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate)
FROM   CarOrder
WHERE  OrderID = ?`

Comment: Why are you calling `executeUpdate` when your SQL doesn't represent an update? I think that's at the heart of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `ResultSet`

You need to capture the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), and access the rows of that `ResultSet` (in this case a single row). If you are executing a query, call `executeQuery` on your `PreparedStatement`, thereby producing a `ResultSet`.

Use the modern [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close your database resources. You can drop the `finally` clauses; no need to call `closeXXX` on your database resources as that chore is handled for you.

I have *not* tried executing the following code example, but I hope it is close to what you need. I am using the alternate `SELECT` line suggested in comment by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith); I’ve not put thought into that as it is not the core of your Question.

```
String sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF( DAY , StartDate , EndDate ) FROM CarOrder WHERE OrderID = ? ;" ;

Integer diff = null ;
try ( 
        Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ; 
    ) {
        pstmt.setInt( 1 , orderId ) ; 
        try ( 
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        ) {
            while ( rs.next ( ) ) {
                diff = rs.getInt( 1 ) ;  // Auto-boxing `int` to `Integer`.
            }
        }
    }
} catch ( SQLException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace ( );  // Handle error condition however you see fit.
}

if( null == diff ) {
    System.out.println( "mission failed." ) ;
} else {
    System.out.println( "mission succeeded. Diff is: " + diff ) ;
}
```

For real work, I would also test to make sure I had only one row returned (make sure that `while` loop runs exactly once rather than zero or more than once).

If this is not clear to you about the various database resources (DataSource, Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet), you should put down the [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and do some more study of the [Oracle Tutorial on JDBC matters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html), and do some searching/studying of Stack Overflow on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of the query in the ResultSet object, and then pick the value of the appropriate column by using of {YOUR_RESULT_SET}.getYourDataType(columnNumber).